# JAXB Key Value problrm

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

So what I am looking to do is to achieve this structure:

```
<root>
   <child>value</child>
   <child>value</child>
   .
   .
</root>
```

The problem is I do not know how many children are there in advances, so need a list. I have tried this but I end up with:

```
<root>
   <child/>
   <child/>
   .
   .
</root>
```

This is using JAXB.

Please help me out..

Comment: um,.... show your code perhaps?

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: @Liggy: if he's even using a schema. If not, then again he'll need to show code and its annotations.

Comment: I would give code but this is for work and I was thinking if someone could give me an  example of how to achieve this. If it is very necessary then I will probably write a dummy.

Comment: hmm would @XmlValue be any help?

Comment: Have a list of child... in root class

Comment: Okey so using @XmlValue solved the proble. THanks every one anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so What I did was added a new annotation and setter and getter methods and it worked eg:

@XmlValue
                protected String myval;

```
            public String getMyval(){
                return this.myval;
            }

            public void setMyval(String myval){
                this.myval = myval;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do one the following:

**Option #1**

***Root***

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    List<String> child;

}
```

**Option #2**

***Root***

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    List<Child> child;

}
```

***Child***

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {
    @XmlValue
    String value;
```

}

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html